# tomcat server's port number not changing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have J2EE application and I want to change the port number of my tomcat server.

I have changed the `Connector` tag to

```
<Connector port="8091" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

But its still giving error `Port is already used`.

Do we need to change somewhere else too ?

Comment: While starting the server its giving problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ports in default tomcat installations: 8005, 8009 and 8080. You'll need to change all of them.

Just search for `port=` in server.xml and change all the values.

Answer (score 2):

may be your 8091 port is occupied try from command port how many ports are in use using `netstat -ano` which will give you already used port

Comment: I have tried with same command but the port 8091 is not used by any other process.

Comment: try different port just for try let say 8123

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue until I figured that I had a "CATALINA_HOME" environment variable pointing to another tomcat folder. So changing the port in the server.xml file had no effect since it wasn't the one readed at startup.

I simply removed (using REM) this line in startup.bat :

```
    REM if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you are not using doors in another program.
The default ports in server.xml is as follows:

Tomcat admin port :  8005
HTTP/1.1 : 8080
AJP/1.3 : 8009

I believe that will resolve this problem.